# DateTime Calculation Error InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-mvc, timespan

I am trying to calculate the number of days someone is on a list. I keep getting the error:

InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.

This is the code in the model:

```
public int ListDay
{
   get
   {
      DateTime valueNow = DateTime.Now;
      DateTime valueRefer = (DateTime)WaitlistReferralDate;

      TimeSpan lday = valueNow - valueRefer;
      int day = (int)lday.TotalDays;
      return day;
    }
}
```

The code in the view

```
<td>
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ListDay)
</td>
```

***UPDATE***
Thank you all for the help this is what ended up working:

```
public int ListDay
        {
            get
            {
                DateTime valueNow = DateTime.Now;
                DateTime? valueRefer = this.WaitlistReferralDate;

                if (valueRefer == null)
                {
                    return 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    TimeSpan lday = (TimeSpan)(valueNow - valueRefer);
                    int day = (int)lday.TotalDays;
                    return day;
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?  What is the type of `WaitlistReferralDate` and the value assigned to it?

Comment: What is the type of `WaitlistReferralDate` ?

Comment: Sorry WaitlistReferralDate is type DateTime?

Comment: Your `WaitlistReferralDate` is most probably null

Comment: Please provide more information. In which line did you get the excepetion? What is WaitlistReferralDate etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure `WaitlistReferralDate` is not null like @Loong said.

```
public class TestModel
{
    public DateTime? date1 { get; set; }

    public int ListDay
    {
        get
        {
            DateTime valueNow = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime? valueRefer = date1;
            TimeSpan lday = valueNow - valueRefer;
            int day = (int)lday.TotalDays;
            return day;
        }
    }
}

public IActionResult Index()
{
    DateTime a = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2);
    var model = new TestModel { date1 = a };
    return View(model);
}

@model TestModel

 <input asp-for="date1" class="form-control" />
 <input asp-for="ListDay" class="form-control" />
```

[image]

Comment: Answer is correct, but `date1` should be of type `DateTime?` to match OP's case.